# Form variable is blank

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass some variable's values through the form. But in the URL I get: `coniugazione=`  and the value passed is blank.

this is my code:

```
<form action="risultato.php?coniugazione=<?php $_POST['coniugazione'] ?>" " method="post">
```

NB: the coniugazione variable is correct valorized from the user. The problem is only the passage to url. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Did you mean to use GET? POST is only there when the user sent a form previously..

Comment: I've also tried with GET method but the value isn't passed..

Comment: If you want to POST a variable, don't add it as a GET parameter, but add an hidden input type *in the form*:  `<input type="hidden" name="coniugazione" value="<?php $_POST['coniugazione'] ?>"/>`

Comment: ok thank's to all. I've fixed my problem with your hints. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to ouput the variable actually in your form with the `echo`-keyword, like: `<?php echo $_POST['coniugazione'] ?>`

**Notice:** This only works if you want to pass the variable via the *GET*-method. If you want to use *POST*, you have to use e.g. a *hidden field* as @alexander correctly suggested in his comment.